# What webserver did Reddit use when it was originally written in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, reddit, hunchentoot

I'm trying to read through the code of `Reddit1.0` located here:

https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit1.0

But it's difficult to understand how the architecture of the website works without an understanding of how the website is served. The reddit code here does not appear to contain any type of server, thus it must have been imported somewhere else and then run, with like `Hunchentoot` or something. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Just a guess, but probably Apache, since it's the most common webserver.

Comment: Why do you think the webserver matters? If it uses standard interfaces (e.g. CGI) it should run on any conforming webserver.

Comment: it matters because the webserver will have a specific way of interacting with the code and helps you read it? For example, there is no `main` function in the repo. The webserver must call the package in some way.

Comment: Lisp doesn't need a `main` function. It's similar to scripting languages, it just executes all the top-level code. So it just runs the file similar to running a Python script or bash script. I assume the script uses CGI to get parameters.

Comment: python does have main functions for packages... Are you saying that all the top level code, in each file in the directory, runs? In that case, what order?

Comment: When you type `python scriptname.py` it just runs all the code in that script. In Lisp, you do `(load "filename.lisp")` and it runs the top-level code in that file.

Comment: but if you follow the link here: https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit1.0 you can see there are many files in the directory. It's a package. There's not one single file to load...

Comment: if it was python, the package might have one file with a `main` function, that would run if you called `python -m <package>`

Comment: It loads all of them. There's a `.asd` file that specifies the dependencies, this causes them to be loaded in the correct order. The last file will presumably end with a function call that gets everything going (similar to the way a Python script will end with `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`)

Comment: @MikeFlynn it's not a package: it's a system, defined using ASDF.  It may be (and is) *in* a package, or several packages.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed, it is about software tools - about webservers, and the question assists in reading code... the moderation here is opressive!

Comment: @MikeFlynn: yes, this is weird.  I'm not going to cast a vote to reopen it since my answer is here and it might be seen as karma-whoring, but it's weird

Comment: https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit1.0/blob/master/reddit.asd shows what software it uses. TBNL is the webserver.

Comment: @barmar it matters since it was a Lisp-based webserver and did not use CGI or other "standard interface".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses [Hunchentoot](https://edicl.github.io/hunchentoot/), under its old name of 'TBNL'.  You can see that by looking at the ASDF file, where it depends on a system named `tbnl`.  Then if you look at the end of `web.lisp` you can see it set `*dispatch-table*` to glue itself into Hunchentoot / TBNL.  I imagine it ran Hunchentoot behind some kind of front-end server.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated fork that upgraded TBNL to Hunchentoot as we use it today, and that added DB migrations for PostGres. So in theory this reddit1.0 fork is runnable:

https://github.com/tamurashingo/reddit1.0/

I have an issue when loading it though:

```
Component CLSQL-UFFI-SYSTEM::UFFI does not match version 2.0,
required by #<SYSTEM "clsql-uffi">
```

and I didn't investigate further.